# How to find the variational result of this functional according to the definition of textbook

Tags: variational-calculus

I see this variational problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214862/how-to-find-the-variation-of-this-functional-according-to-the-definition-of-lagr).

The functional is :
$$J(y)=y^{2}(x_{0})+\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}}(xy+y'^{2}) dx$$
In the textbook, the result of finding the functional variation according to the functional variation defined by Lagrange is :

[image]

The variation sign δ has the following basic operational properties :

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

How to use MMA to define a correlation function and find the variation of this function according to the definition of Lagrange?

**I really want to solve this problem**, but when I replace `y` with `y+ε*δ`, it can't be expanded linearly, so I can't do further calculation.

```
f[x] /. f :> f + ε*δ
f'[x] + f[x] /. f :> f + ε*δ
```

I want to get the following result according to the linear operation rule of variation mentioned above:

```
f[x] + ε*δ f[x]
(f'[x] + ε*δ f'[x]) + (f[x] + ε*δ f[x])
```

But the above code cannot be expanded obviously. **Please help me**.

The title of the book is 《变分法基础》, the author is 老大中. And the relevant content is on page 59 to page 63.

[image]

You can get a photocopy of this book from [here](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1lStmDJFWo-WvqPkSd6qaAg). The password of the online disk is `wthj`.

Comment: have you seen [`EulerEquations`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/VariationalMethods/ref/EulerEquations.html)?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Yes. I've seen the built-in `VariationalMethods` function package, but I want to do a similar custom function to solve variational problem according to the textbook definition.

Comment: Please provide the title and author of the textbook.

Comment: @LouisB I'm sorry, the textbook is written in Chinese. The title of the book is called《变分法基础》, the author is 老大中 and the relevant content is from page 59 to page 63.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the formal variation for the given functional we can use

```
J[y_, x_, x0_, x1_] := (y^2 /. {x -> x0}) + Integrate[x y + D[y, x]^2, {x, x0, x1}]
varJ[J_, y_, x_, x0_, x1_] := D[J[y + epsilon delta[y], x, x0, x1], epsilon] /. {epsilon -> 0}

varJ[J, y[x], x, x0, x1]
```

Regarding the result obtained

$$
\delta J(y) = 2\delta(y(x_0))y(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^{x_1}(x\delta(y)+2\delta'(y)(y')^2)dx
$$

NOTE

The operator should be able to detect

$$
\delta'(y)(y')^2 = (\delta(y))'y' = (\delta(y)y')'-\delta(y)y''
$$

concluding with

$$
\int_{x_0}^{x_1}(x\delta(y)+2\delta'(y)(y')^2)dx = \int_{x_0}^{x_1}(x-2y'')\delta(y)dx-\delta(y)y'|_{x_0}^{x_1}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. But your variational sign $δ$ does not perform the variational correlation operation like the differential sign $d$, and the result is not consistent with that in the textbook.

Comment: The operator $\delta(y)$ performs an action very similar to a differentiation. With the results in hand, we can choose which properties apply.

Comment: This is what I mean. Can you write down the specific implementation process?

Comment: Please. See attached note.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the result of the code above is `2 y[x0] delta[y[x0]] + 
 Integrate[(2 Derivative[1][y][x]^2 Derivative[1][delta][y[x]] + 
     x delta[y[x]]) \[DifferentialD]x, {x, x0, x1}]`, while the result of the textbook is `2 y[x0] delta[y[x0]] + 
 Integrate[(2 Derivative[1][y][x] Derivative[1][delta][y[x]] + 
     x delta[y[x]]) \[DifferentialD]x, {x, x0, x1}]`, they are slightly different.How to modify them to be the same?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if [`` VariationalMethods`VariationalD ``](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/VariationalMethods/ref/VariationalD.html) works properly for this problem, but worthy of trying, I suppose.

```
<< VariationalMethods`

Clear[J]
J = y[x0]^2 + Integrate[x y[x] + y'[x]^2, {x, x0, x1}];

VariationalD[J, y[x], x]
```

> 1/2 (-x0^2 + x1^2)

Comment: I want a result like I want a result like  2 y[x0] δ[y[x0]] + 
 Integrate[(x δ[y[x]] + 
    2 Derivative[1][y][x] δ[y'[x]]), {x, x0, x1}]   **or**

 2 y[x0] δ[y[x0]] + 
 Integrate[(x δ[y[x]] + 
    2 Derivative[1][y][x] δ'[y[x]]), {x, x0, x1}] .

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes OK, `VariationalD` returns the variational derivative, which is not what you want for the moment.