# How to use `Through` function to pass through derivative operator

Tags: operators

Because of the need of the operation rules of variational notation, I want to achieve the following effects:

```
Through[(f + s)'[x]]
Through[(f + s)''[x]]
```

I want to get the following results:

```
f'[x] + s'[x]
f''[x] + s''[x]
```

I need a general and easy way to achieve the above requirements. What should I do?

As mentioned below, LouisB's method can be used to solve the problem of single replacement, but how to realize the whole replacement for complex formula?

```
y[x0] + y[x] + y'[x] + x*y''[x]
```

I want to replace the function header y with y + ε*δ*y to get something like this:

```
y[x0] + ε*δ[y[x0]] + 
 y[x] + ε*δ[y[x]] + 
 y'[x] + ε*δ[y'[x]] + 
 x (y''[x] + ε*δ[y''[x]])
```

In addition, for the following cases:

```
replaceHead = # /. 
    h : (y | 
        Derivative[_][y]) :> (Times[ε, δ@
         h[#]] &) &;
expr = (y[x0]^2) + Integrate[x y[x] + D[y[x], x]^2, {x, x0, x1}];
expr + replaceHead@expr
```

I need the results like this:

```
2 y[x0] δ[y[x0]] + 
 Integrate[(x δ[y[x]] + 
    2 Derivative[1][y][x] δ'[y[x]]), {x, x0, x1}]
```

But kglr's method can't combine integrals to get the form I want.

Comment: `Through[Distribute[(f + s)'][x]]`  and `Through[Distribute[(f + s)''][x]]`

Comment: @LouisB Thank you very much for your help. I have updated my question. Can you spare time to solve it?

Comment: PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes, it is impossible to follow how your requirements in the two updates are related to the previous one. Your first update says a term like `x y[x]` is should become  `x (y[x] + ε*δ[y[x]])`, you second says it should become `x δ[y[x]]`. What happened to `ε` between your first update and the second?

Comment: @kglr In fact, my goal in updating the problem is to solve [`this problem`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215063/how-to-find-the-variational-result-of-this-functional-according-to-the-definitio) finally. It's better to answer this question directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[replaceHead]
replaceHead = # /. h : (y | Derivative[_][y]) :> (Times[ε, δ @ h[#]] &) &;
```

***Example:***

```
expr = y[x0] + y[x] + y'[x] + x*y''[x];

desired = y[x0] + ε*δ[y[x0]] + y[x] + ε*δ[y[x]] + y'[x] + ε*δ[y'[x]] + x (y''[x] + ε*δ[y''[x]]);

res = expr + replaceHead @ expr;

res == Simplify[desired]
```

> True

```
TeXForm @ res
```

> $\varepsilon  x \delta \left(y''(x)\right)+x y''(x)+\varepsilon  \delta \left(y'(x)\right)+y'(x)+\varepsilon  \delta
>    (y(x))+y(x)+\varepsilon  \delta (y(\text{x0}))+y(\text{x0})$

Comment: Thank you very much. I've updated the question. Your method can't combine  integrals to get the result form I want. I hope you can modify it again.

Comment: After executing your code for the expression `expr = (y[x0]^2) + Integrate[x y[x] + D[y[x], x]^2, {x, x0, x1}]`, the result is    `Integrate[(ε^2 δ[
      Derivative[1][y][x]]^2 + ε x δ[y[x]]), {x, 
   x0, x1}] + 
 Integrate[(Derivative[1][y][x]^2 + x y[x]), {x, x0, 
   x1}] + ε^2 δ[y[x0]]^2 + y[x0]^2` , while the result of the textbook is `2 y[x0] δ[y[x0]] + 
 Integrate[(2 Derivative[1][y][x] Derivative[1][δ][y[x]] + 
     x δ[y[x]]) , {x, x0, x1}]`. How to modify it?

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes, this answer is meant to solve the question posed in your previous edit (for expressions like `y[x0] + y[x] + y'[x] + x*y''[x]`). Naturally, it will not  work for _arbitrary_ input expression.

Comment: Thank you very much, but how to find a general solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't insist on using [`Through`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html), this is probably what you are looking for.

```
y[x0] + y[x] + y'[x] + x*y''[x];
% /. {Derivative[n_][y_][x_] :>  Derivative[n][y][x] + ϵ δ[Derivative[n][y][x]], 
      y_[x_] :>  y[x] + ϵ δ[y[x]]}
```

> [image]

or to make it shorter

```
y[x0] + y[x] + y'[x] + x*y''[x];
% /. expr : Derivative[_][_][_] | _[_] :> expr + ϵ δ[expr]
```

Comment: Your answer is great and thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

```
 Plus @@ D[Through[{f, s}[x]], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plus @@ D[Through[{f, s}[x]], {x, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much, but I need to replace all the `f ''[x]` in the formula with `(f + δ)'' [x]` when I do the variational operation, so your method can't meet my operation requirements.